# FileNotFoundException, could not read contents from jar?

Tags: android, build, filenotfoundexception, sign, jar-signing

I'm having the worst time trying to update my app. I finally got it to build and run on my phone, but when I try to export signed application package, I get two errors:

```
Could not read jar file contents from *\TapForTap.jar
Could not read jar file contents from *\GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-6.0.1.jar
```

I've tried all of the usual deleting/reimporting, cleaning, exiting/restarting Eclipse. Nothing has worked. And yes, Is Library is checked. Any other ideas?

EDIT:

Here is one of the errors:

```
    eclipse.buildId=M20120208-0800
java.version=1.7.0_07
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product

    Error
    Mon Oct 29 16:24:24 MST 2012
    Could not read jar file contents from \Expansion Free\TapForTap.jar

        java.io.FileNotFoundException: \Expansion Free\TapForTap.jar (The system cannot find the path specified)
            at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
            at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
            at com.android.tools.lint.client.api.LintDriver.findClasses(LintDriver.java:1142)
            at com.android.tools.lint.client.api.LintDriver.checkClasses(LintDriver.java:932)
            at com.android.tools.lint.client.api.LintDriver.runFileDetectors(LintDriver.java:785)
            at com.android.tools.lint.client.api.LintDriver.checkProject(LintDriver.java:661)
            at com.android.tools.lint.client.api.LintDriver.analyze(LintDriver.java:288)
            at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.lint.LintJob.run(LintJob.java:151)
            at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
```

Comment: Did you try running Eclipse as Admin? It was my problem once.

Comment: Make sure that you're selected Add External JAR in your project and not just "Add Jar File" (or whatever the alternative is). Also, make sure you select and update the Order and Export tab in project properties

Comment: Added as external jars. Still no luck. What should be selected in Order and Export?